# Best way to upload images to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js

Background: Currently trying to implement a feature so that users on my site can upload their profile image to GCS.

I understand that there are two ways you could upload objects when using the client library:

The standard way (see here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) and 2. doing it with a Signed URL (see here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-upload-signed-url-v4)

Just wondering which way would be better for my particular use case?

Comment: Please post your code, I'm not sure how we can help without it...I'm not going to use your post to recreate it myself as it is

Comment: This isn't a coding query? I'm more interested in which of the two above approaches I've listed would be suitable given my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link requires the user to upload their objects to your server (running Node.js) and then your server uploads the objects to Google Cloud Storage. This common method ensures security as the objects can be scanned before uploading to Cloud Storage.

Signed URLs are usually recommended because the client uploads directly to Cloud Storage bypassing your server.

The best method depends on the size of the objects, reliability of the client's networks, security objectives, network costs (ingress and egress), how trusted the clients are, etc.